# GitHub Desktopは使える？機能不足？

Tags: git, github-desktop

Git初心者です。
以前SouceTreeの勉強をしたことがあるのですが(複雑で挫折し)
今改めてGitHub Desktopを使ってみると、

「フェッチ・プル・プッシュが1つのボタンに集約されていたり」
「ツリー形状のビジュアルも無い」などと、
概念がかなり簡略化されていて、
(ツリーも意識せずに)ただブランチを作って、コミットして、プッシュするだけのような感じ、
ようやく使える？感じになりました。

逆に、
「ブランチ以外(タグやHEAD・過去のコミット)にはチェックアウト出来ない」
「ツリー形状がない」
「ターミナルを呼出すボタン等もない」
等というのは、

「それを使わなくても、GitHubの最小限の機能(プルリクなど)で十分に効果を発揮するから、簡略化されている」
という認識で良いでしょうか？ (勉強の幅を広げたほうが良いのか、一旦このまま進めたほうが良いのか知りたいためです)

もしくは、「単純にGitHub Desktopの開発が追いついていないだけで、
最小限の機能だけでは、(現場にもよると思いますが) 正直実践では使えなくて、ターミナルや他GUIツールを使っていく必要がある」
という形でしょうか？

Comment: 本筋とはあまり関係が無いかもしれませんが、「ターミナルを呼出すボタン等もない」というのは半分正しくなくて、エディタ＆ターミナルを呼び出す機能はあり、現在のバージョンだとメニューやショートカットキーから使えます。

Answer (score 2):

あるソフトウェアが開発者一般にとって使用に堪えるものかどうかは客観的な評価がしづらいのでその方向で答えることは避け、GitHub Desktop がどういう目的で開発され今後どういう風に開発されていく予定だと公開されているのか、を答えます。

GitHub Desktop が公式の文書を出しており、そこから引用します。

https://github.com/desktop/desktop/blob/development/docs/process/what-is-desktop.md

> **3. GitHub Desktop prioritizes workflows for beginners and collaborative teams.**
>   We want to create an inclusive and approachable way for developers to turn ideas into reality, and we see GitHub Desktop as critical in reducing the intimidation of working with Git on the command line. Users of all experience levels will continue to benefit from GitHub Desktop’s features but when we have to choose between workflows for advanced Git users and workflows for beginner Git users, we prioritize beginners. Additionally, we think it’s foundational to support solo development, but our unique value comes from combining the power of GitHub with the convenience of working locally so that you can collaborate with your team easily. This also means GitHub Desktop will likely not support workflows that are unique to your team, against documented best practice, or different from the vast majority of developers.

特に "we prioritize beginners" の部分が参考になるかなと思います。つまり、GitHub を使う人全員が使いやすいように設計されているものの、既に git をターミナル等で柔軟に使える人よりかは git 初心者が簡単に git を使えるような設計になっています。

<sub>補記：やり方や設計思想へもっと具体的に切り込んだ回答が欲しい場合、今回のように機能全般について問う形の質問の替わりに「GitHub Desktop で○○という機能を行うには？」みたく評価の基準が分かりやすい形の質問を新たにしていただけると、「それはこうしたらできる」「まだ実装されていないけど予定はある」「こういう理由で実装される見通しは薄い」のような回答を書きやすいです。</sub>

Comment: せっかくの日本語 SO なのでオレオレ翻訳を付けていただけると幸せになれる人が増えそうです。

Comment: そのページの`1.`の最後の文の方が端的でしょう。併せて引用・翻訳しておいてください。

Comment: @774RR さん、引用部分が長く全部和訳すると読みにくくなりそうだったので、勝手に翻訳するのではなく要点だと考えている部分をまとめてみました（ほとんど元の英文と似た構造になってしまいましたが……）

Comment: @kunif さん、わたしはそうは思っていません（敢えて 3 を選んでいます）。翻訳するのもゼロコストではないので、kunif さんがご自身で回答していただければ幸いです。

Comment: (会話として成り立たせるために) 自分の言葉である質問や回答は日本語が必須ですが、参考文献などに関しては訳してあれば "親切" であれ、投稿者に負担を強いるのは少し違うかなぁという気がします。 /細かいニュアンスを正しく伝えるのも慣れが必要ですし、機械翻訳を貼るだけならあまり意味は無いかと。

Comment: 1つの回答を改良していくのもStackOverflowの思想に適っていると思っていたのですが、言い方が丸投げで指示したように見えるので良くなかったですね。気を付けます。

Answer (score 1):

GitHub Desktop もそれなりに開発歴のあるツールだと思うので "開発が追い付いてない" というよりも
"必要最小限の機能に絞って" が設計思想としてありそうです。

ツールに何をどこまで求めるかは人それぞれですが、私は Git のGUIクライアントとして [GitKraken](https://www.gitkraken.com/) を利用しています。GitHub Desktop よりも出来ることは多いですが、個人的にはコミットグラフの表示用に使っている程度で、実際にはコマンドラインでの操作がメインです。

Answer (score 1):

既に回答されている内容と大した違いは無く、蛇足に近いですが。

@nekketsuuu さん紹介のページ全体をGoogle翻訳等に通して見てみるのが吉かなと。

その中で質問に一番短く答えているのが以下の文と思われます。
つまり全ての機能・要求を単独のソフトウェアで叶えるものではありませんよ、ということです。

(太字は引用者)

> 1. GitHub Desktop reduces frustration and makes Git and GitHub workflows* more approachable.
>
> GitHub Desktop is not a replacement for the functionality of Git, but a tool to enable you and your team to be more productive.
>
> **GitHub DesktopはGitの機能に代わるものではなく、** あなたとあなたのチームの生産性を向上させるツールです。

Comment: みなさま

ありがとうございます。

やはり、最小限のシンプルな機能、つまり私にとっては、
これで勉強していって良さそうと安心できました。